# Iterating Active class to two row nav bar in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm working with a WordPress site, using the ACF plugin and I have navigation that is in two rows. The first row `<li>` NEEDS to be `class="active"` to second row even show up. I can get either the first row to show up as active, or second but not both.

To make things more fun, there is no reliable way to figure this using child-pages (it was tried). Some of nav objects are parent pages and I have no power over that.

And since the goal is to get this working with templates, hardcoding page names isn't an option either..

I somehow have to to "go back" in code if inner `<li>` is marked as active.

**ACF fields:**

ACF has upper nav with name, link and sub-navigation repeater.
and sub-navigation repeater has name and link for every sub-page.

In code there is `<li>` tags inside `<li>` tags iterated using ACF repeater and while have rows. $lang_code is used to figure from where to pull header texts.

```
<?php
$lang = get_locale();
$curr_page = get_permalink(); ?>


<nav role="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation">

    <?php if (have_rows('navigation', $lang_code)) :
        while(have_rows('navigation', $lang_code)) : the_row() ?>

            <li class="<?php  if($curr_page == get_sub_field('link') ){ echo 'active'; } ?>">
                <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link') ?>"> <?php the_sub_field('name') ?></a>
                <ul class="sub-navigation">

                    <?php if (have_rows('sub-navigation', $lang_code)) :
                    while(have_rows('sub-navigation', $lang_code)) : the_row() ?>

                        <li class="<?php if($curr_page == get_sub_field('link')){ echo 'active';  } ?>"><a href="<?php the_sub_field('link') ?>"><?php the_sub_field('name') ?></a></li>

                    <?php endwhile; //end sub while
                    endif; //end sub if ?>

                </ul>
            </li>

    <?php
        endwhile; // End navigation while
        endif; // End navigation if

    </ul>
</nav>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCtYO.jpg

**Pictures**, first one: FAQ is class="active", but since Support is not, nothing is shown. The second picture is while support is class="active", showing second row of links (with support active since they happen to be same page).

I've tried all kinds of parent iterating and counters in nav columns, but I still have no working answer.

I am considering going jQuery + PHP or something like that.

Comment: Is the last "`<?php`" missing a "`?>`"?

Comment: You have not even asked a question here.  All you done is stated some things that are happening.  If you have an actual question then ask it, don't imply it.  Use a question mark.

Answer (score -1):

Try using jQuery:

`$('.sub-navigation li.active').parents('li').addClass('active');`

Code above add `.active` class to parent `<li>` of child that has `.active` class.